# C++ virtual method: best way to use base implementation with an addition

Tags: c++, virtual-functions

Say I have the following classes:

```
class Airplane
{
    virtual bool Fly(uint64_t destinationID)
    {
        //Do what an airplane does to be flown.
    }

    /*
     *  More function and data members.
     */
}

class SomeModel: public Airplane
{
    virtual bool Fly(uint64_t destinationID);
    {
       //Do something that SomeModel specifically should do before it gets flying.  

       //Do exactly what Airplane::Fly does.
    }
}
```

My question is how to implement SomeModel::Fly. One simple way is as follows:

```
virtual bool SomeModel::Fly(uint64_t destinationID)
{
    //Do something that SomeModel specifically should do before it gets flying.  

    Airplane::Fly(destinationID);
}
```

Is there a nicer way of doing it? Or is there another reason for choosing another way. I know this is a general question but it's the first time I have to implement such a method so I want to make sure I'm not missing anything.

**EDIT**

I find it worth to emphasize that Airplane is not a general or abstract class, many Airplane in the company are just airplanes and appear as such without any inhritance, there is one specific model though that has some specific behavior.

Comment: The way show is the correct way to do it. What don't you like about it?

Comment: I just wasn't sure that this is the way since I never encountered something similar.

Comment: You may want to read up on Design Patterns, specifically, on the Template Method pattern (not to be confused with C++ function templates).

Comment: I think you could use the template method pattern. Did you concider this?

Comment: n.m. and elmes, I have edited my question. Do you still refer me to the Template Method pattern?

Comment: yes it is still applicable.

Comment: @n.m. Thanks. Did you mean like what Mats answered?

Comment: Yes that's how it works more or less.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This really depends on what you are trying to achieve. Your example is certainly valid and one solution to one type of problem (where a some setup or other variations are required early on).

Another variant on this theme is to use a virtual setup, and then a common "fly" method.

So:

```
class Airplane
{
   bool Fly(uint64_t destinationID)
   {
      SetupForFlight();
      // do actual flying stuff
      ...  
      ...
   }

   virtual void SetupForFlight() { // do nothing for standard airplane }
}

class Boeing747: public Airplane
{
    ...
    void SetupForFLight() 
    {
       ... do stuff that needs to be set up here. 
    }
    ...
}
```

There are benefits with both of these methods, and it will probably depend on what you are modelling which is better.

Of course, you could have a `AfterLanding` type function at the end of `Fly` as well.

Just out of curiousity, are there so many destinations that you need a 64-bit value for them - I've never really considered it, just curious.

Edit: I think what I'm describing is a "Template method pattern". I'm not great with names for these things, I just know how it's working....